# Excel: Prevent external workbook open?

Tags: excel, dialog, vsto

in my VSTO Excel Add-In I sometimes have an open (modal) form to choose some parameters to operate some operations in the active worksheet. After the user hits "OK" the dialog is closed and the long running server operation is triggered. After that, the data in the active worksheet is updated.

Now my problem:
One of our testers did a test were he opens the modal dialog and then externally opens another workbook (by the jumplist in the Windows7 taskbar). Nothing happens until he hit "OK" to leave the modal dialog. Then Excel opens the other workbook. But then I have lost my active worksheet and could not properly continue.

Any "internal" open operation is prevented just by having this modal dialog.

**But is it possible to prevent the "external" workbook open???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one (crude) way to prevent an external workbook open:

If I go to the edit mode of a worksheet tab (not in its cells) then an external workbook open is ignored. The open operation via Explorer double click on an Excel file and will also not resumed when I leave the worksheet tab edit mode.

I don't know if I really should use this "feature" to prevent external open operations to happen... :-/

I just want to share it. Sorry for self answering, Jörg

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way of trapping that, but you can make sure that your spreadsheet is the only one it operates on, regardless of what else is open

If you `set` another variable to the name of the workbook, then you can use that name, and it won't matter if they have another worksheet open

e.g. instead of

```
Activeworkbook.Sheet("Data").Range("B7") = 7
```

you save the workbook info:

```
Dim DataWorkbook as workbook
Set DataWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
```

Later, you can use that reverence, and it will operate on the expected workbook

```
DataWorkbook.Sheet("Data").Range("B7") = 7
```